# Curl to postgres in separate vagrant environment

Tags: postgresql, curl, vagrant

I am attempting to set up an environment with two vagrant machines. One contains an application (portal) and a postgres database instance and the other contains an API (api) from which I wish to run curl commands to query the portal database.

Through using private network in vagrant

Portal Environment

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 5432         -- Fix
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../Base", "/Base"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../alacrity-v2-api", "/API"
end
```

Database.yml

```
development: &development
  adapter: postgresql
  database: payments_development
  username: payments
  password: payments
  host:     localhost
  port:     5432
  pool: 10
  reconnect: true
  min_messages: warning
```

API Environment

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3002, host: 3002
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"     --Fix
  config.vm.synced_folder "../Base", "/Base"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
  end

end
```

Database.yml

```
development: &development
  adapter: postgresql
  database: chsh
  host: 192.168.33.10
  port: 3000
  username: payments
  password: payments
  database: payments_development
  pool: 10
```

Now when i run my curl command (removed basic auth password for security reasons):

```
curl -v -L http://localhost:9292/v2.2/ -H "Authorization: Basic ??????????????????????????"
```

The following is returned in my API environment

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 9292 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
> GET /v2.2/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:9292
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic emFpbmFnZ3JlZ180MTZfbGl2ZTo4b3Jlc3B1Y3Jv
>
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Content-Length: 6866
<
Puma caught this error: received invalid response to SSL negotiation: H
 (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

While in my Portal environment I get this:

```
Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `execute'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/request.rb:84:in `parse'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run_machine'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
        /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-3.2.22/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        script/rails:6:in `require'
        script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone help me understand what the issue is or how I could go about diagnosing the problem.

Comment: you're not forwarding port `9292` so you run curl against your host directly, not the guest

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean?

Comment: you run `curl -v -L http://localhost:9292/v2.2/` so on port `9292` but you're not forwarding this port in your Vagrantfile config (`config.vm.network "forwarded_port"` only forwards `3002`)

Comment: I thought that's what you meant but upon trying this I continue to get the same error. I added "config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9292, host: 5432"

Comment: ok just to make sure - in this case you do curl on 5432 port right ?

Comment: Sorry. I do a curl localhost:9292 as it is initially running the API in the environment the curl is ran from. From there I want the API to query the database which is why my database.yml has host: 192.168.33.10 and port: 3000 (not sure this is right). From that the database on the second machine is queried due to its vagrantfile private_network ip 192.168.33.10

Answer (score 0):

Edited the question to show my working configuration. One of the main issues I believe was the acceptance of a connection from the other VM. Had edited pg_hba.conf and added

host    all     all      *      trust

based on an answer from elsewhere. Ended up adding a few more variations to ensure I was covered. Lines added include:

host    all     all     192.168.33.11    trust
host    all     all     192.168.33.11    md5
host    all     all     *                trust

Also take a look at the vagrantfiles. They might not be perfect but it got it working so I'm happy enough. Hope this helps someone else banging their head against a wall.